# How can jmeter controller executes after 9 requests

Tags: jmeter

How can i execute my j meter controller to run after 9 requests. i tried to run controller every after 9 requests to get token. token expires after 9 requests.
what controller i need to use, do i need to put any conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can put your request(s) under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) in order to execute it(them) specified number of times.
2. The request for getting the token can be placed under [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) where you can use i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) so the token request will be executed only one of 9 times

Example setup:

[image]